# Automating the finding of hidden correlations‏

Tags: correlation

With this dummy data below , can I get a tool to brute force figure out that penalties column has the highest correlation to wins?    I would like to try a simple data set using this (or any) tool.   Which free student tool can do this?

[image]

It was this link that gave me the idea of wanting to try for myself
http://blog.nutonian.com/how-we-beat-nate-silver

Comment: I do not see any connection between your reference and what you are attempting to do.  Eureqa certainly does not attempt to find the variable having the highest correlation with the response (number of wins).  In fact, by fitting *nonlinear* models it is not looking directly at correlations.

Comment: Then what exactly is the blog post about?  They are taking a data set they know nothing about, and finding the column that is most correlated with wins.  Correct?

Comment: Not correct.  They wish to be able to predict wins accurately based on all the variables: that is a very different thing!

Comment: Isn't it just all correlation?  They are doing a multiple variable correlation.  But, the one with the biggest coefficient might have the biggest influence (or largest correlation?)

Comment: No, that just is not true. You need to learn the basics of multiple regression.  Although you can find much advice about that here, the best place to start would be a good introductory textbook.

Comment: I used R to create a correlation matrix.  This is exactly what I was asking about. Very simple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used R to create a correlation matrix.  This is exactly what I was asking about. Very simple.